# How do I shrink an SD Card image?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, images, sd-card

I imaged a 16 GB SD card using the dd command. The card however, does not have more than 4 GB of data on it across 2 partitions (FAT32 & ext3).

I would like to transfer this image on to a 8GB SD card. How do I go about shrinking the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming Linux, something like this could be done:

1. Attach the image to a loop device using `losetup`. Do not mount any partitions.

   ```
   0 GB                              8 GB                             16 GB
   |--------fat32--------|--------------------ext3--------------------|
   ```
2. Using `gparted`, shrink the first partition to less than 50% of original size.

   ```
   0 GB                              8 GB                             16 GB
   |--fat32---|          |--------------------ext3--------------------|
   ```
3. Move the second partition to the newly created free space, shrink to <50%.

   ```
   0 GB                              8 GB                             16 GB
   |--fat32---|---------ext3---------|                                |
   ```
4. Ensure that the second partition ends before the 8 GB.
5. Detach the loop device.
6. Truncate the image file to 8 GB.

Note: Usually, you have to first shrink the *filesystem*, then adjust the partition size to match the filesystem. Gparted does this for you in a single "Resize" step, but other tools may not.

Comment: Don't forget: After you do such a 'resize', you won't be able to just DD everything back. "DD" is not for simple backup. It's for byte-by-byte backup. Keeping _every_ information of the device. If you want a simple backup from a device, use .tar.gz, .tar.bz2 (on Linux, these two will keep the permissions). But not DD if you only care about the files and the space.

Comment: @Shiki: The goal is not to backup, but to move entire volumes (incl. filesystems, partition tables, etc.) to a smaller disk.

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry, you're right. **(** I skipped that part. :( **)**

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't just shrink the disk image. There's too much complicated stuff going on inside.

I'm going to suggest you mount the dd image then either copy files across to your new filesystem, or research further on shrinking your specific filesystems rather than the disk.

First off, do you have a copy of the original partition table?

If not, try:
`fdisk -l -u /path/to/image`

Then hopefully you can use the values in the above to do something like:

```
dd if=/path/to/image of=/path/to/output bs=BLOCKSIZE skip=STARTBLOCK count=TOTALBLOCKS
```

(replacing the above capitals as required)

From there, mount the image:

```
mount -o loop /path/to/output /path/to/mountlocation
```

and either copy your data or learn about standard shrinking of your particular file systems and further dd'ing.